# how to graph logarithmic and exponential equations

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I am not looking for the answer to the question, it would be helpful but an explanation would also be very helpful.

How would you graph the following equations?

ln is log base e, while log is log base 10.

y = | 3^x - 2 |

y = ln (x - 4)

y = log base (1/2) (x+2)

y = - log (-x)

y = (5X) / (1 + e^x)

Do I just plot points or is there a specific way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WolframAlpha. It will graph the functions for you.